# H Bridge Motor free wheeling path

Tags: h-bridge

Background:

I am not providing diodes for free wheeling of motor as:
- I have one big capacitor, 100uF
- CW and CCW will be switched with dead band delay of 1.5 to 2.5 seconds

can there be a Hbridge without freewheeling diodes

Answer (score 1):

You do have a freewheel path via R3,4,5,6.

A total of 802R.

If you intend to rely on this route be mindful of the current you want to control to and the equivalent Ri drop as this is the voltage (plus BackEMF) that the Hbridge will need to support.

It isn't the most advisable topology

Comment: I know this is rude. But, can you help me to on how to finding out the back emf generated by a DC Motor?

Comment: This is a motor datasheet parameter. Failing that... If you can spin the rotor at a constant KNOWN speed you can measure the stator terminal voltage to derive Ke.  NOTE: it really isn't advisable to rely on those resistors to provide a freewheel path (at the very least the power rating of those resistors needs to be fully realised, then there is a the voltage that will be generated to enable the stator current to continually flow). Why don't you want to put some diodes down?

Comment: I have placed the diodes now. thank you for your suggestion. What is Ke? Please guide on one reference.

Comment: Ke is the voltage constant (or backEMF constant) of the motor units of Volts/rpm (or equivalent). The faster the rotor is spinning, the more volts are present at its terminals

Answer (score 0):

You are going to blow up all your electronics. Once you will go to dead band state, the motor current will find it's way out by rising voltage. In certain cases to thousands of volts. This is how ignition circuits work.

Comment: Motor is Brushed DC, typical load current is 120 mA in our application and 13 ohm is the resistance (180 mA, stall current). As supply is only 3 V and with huge dead band delay the circuit is safe (It is operating since past 3 years). I am trying to understand how the circuit is handling kick back voltage. Thank you for your response!

Comment: If you have the circuit, try putting oscilloscope on it. You will discover voltage spikes and see where they go. By the way, is it possible, that there are freewheeling diodes that you are not aware of?

Comment: I am sure that there are no other diodes (there are two, one for reset circuit and another for reverse voltage protection of MCU) on the board. I have added the image of voltage across H Bridge. Thanks for the help

Comment: The decay (inductor discharging) happens much faster. So you have to change time base to like 10us/square and trigger on edge.

Comment: I measured it again several times but it is always about 250 300 mV immediately after stalling is stopped.

Comment: Allright, i known what is it. It's the 100R resistor and high side transistor, probably.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24980/discussion-between-umar-and-gregory-kornblum).